# Approaches we can follow to allow our customers to interact with our own APIs using Power Automate Flows

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powerapp, office-integration

I have more than 6 years of experience in Power Automate & SharePoint. but i am working on a new project which created a challenge for me, to understand from where i should start and which approach to take. The general requirements are:-

1. The customer has their own ERP system where almost all the functionalities are exposed as REST APIs.
2. The customer has a centralized ERP system, for their 50++ clients
3. The customer wants to allow clients to interact with their system (through the APIs), where the customer can build their own Power automate flow. So for example before the client add a new payable account to the ERP system, then can create their own Flow >> and have 2 level approvals.

so based on my experience, we can enable this type of integration using 2 approaches:-

1. First approach, is to build our own custom connector & actions>> so users can add the connector to any MS Flow, and start their work..
2. Second approach, is to build some documentations on how the users can call the raw ERP API's through MS Flow, and even we can build sample Flows for the clients to download and customize.

so i am not sure which approach best fit our needs? and why? also is there 3 rd approach i am unaware of that we can use.

Hint, we can have a fast approach to deliver something in 4-5 weeks, and then we can have a long term approach in 5-6 months..so things can be flexible.

Any advice will be highly appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: @theChrisKent are you serious? i posted those 2 questions one for Power automate and the other Power Apps/.have u actually read them ?

Comment: @theChrisKent so you removed your comment, and close this question, seems you ignored what i mentioned in my above comment ?

Comment: I didn't make a comment. I voted to close as a duplicate which I stand by. Your questions are literally the exact same question except you switched Power Apps and Power Automate. As someone who has worked with them since the beginning, you are likely aware that the answers are likely the same or extremely similar and having 2 overly broad, opinion based questions with the same answers isn't helpful.